# Use user input to set Pygame display size

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a simulation, and it needs 3 inputs from the user.
The inputs I need are the X and Y dimensions for the display and a number of iterations.

```
def max_rows():
   while True:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               sys.exit()
           if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
               if event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                   xmax=user_text
               if event.key==pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                   user_text=user_text[:-1]
               else:
                   user_text+=event.unicode
       screen.fill((0,0,0))

       pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,input_rect,2)
       text_surface=base_font.render(user_text,True,(255,255,255))
       screen.blit(text_surface,(input_rect.x+5,input_rect.y+5))

       input_rect.w=max(100,text_surface.get_width()+10)

       pygame.display.flip()
```

I can get the input from the user, but I'm not sure how to use it or how to get the next inputs.

Comment: if you want to set display size then you should get it before `pygame.display.set_mode` and you could use `input()` before running `pygame` - but it needs to run in console. Eventually you could use `argparse` to run script with arguments `python script.py val1 val2 val3`

Comment: maybe before `while True` you should set `user_text = ""` -  and for `K_RETURN` use `return user_text`. And then you can run it as `xmax = max_rows()`

Comment: you could evenit for `x = max_rows()`, `y = max_rows()`, `depth = max_rows()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly two ways of solving this problem:

1 Is to call `inptut()` before the screen is initialized (as suggested by the comments).

2 taking the input after the screen is initialized. can be done by using the `KEYDOWN` events:

```py
import pygame

allowed_chars = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))

input_list = []

current_input = ''
while len(input_list) < 3:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit(0)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                input_list.append(int(current_input))
                current_input = ''
            elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                current_input = current_input[:-1]
            elif chr(event.key) in allowed_chars:
                current_input += chr(event.key)

# do something with your input
```

things you might want to add:

- allowing the user to see what he has typed

```py
pygame.font.init()
courir = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 25)

# in the while loop:
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
screen.blit(courir.render(current_input, False, (0, 0, 0), (30, 30))
pygame.display.flip()
```

- add try - except statements around for the following cases:
  user hits return when nothing is entered
  user hits backspace when nothing is entered
  user hits a key that is not recognized by `chr()`